# Preventing Shortcode Execution with wp_update_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am programmatically updating posts using the following code, the content and excerpt contain nothing more than an HTML comment and shortcode.

```
//Add in Short Codes
$content_short_code = '<!-- Start --> [MY_GREAT_CONTENT] <!-- End -->';
$excerpt_short_code ='<!-- Start --> [MY_GREAT_EXCERPT] <!-- End -->';


$my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_content' => $content_short_code,
      'post_excerpt' => $excerpt_short_code
  );
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

The issue is, when I run the script, I receive errors from the functions that are tied to the shortcodes meaning the shortcodes appear to be executed as they are updated by wp_update_post. It doesn't stop the update and the shortcodes don't execute any logic, but I'd prefer to not have any errors on the run.

Short of disabling the functions whilst I do the update, is there anyway to flag wp_update_post to just consider the content as plain text and not run it?

**Possible Solution**

From comments, add:

```
remove_all_shortcodes();
```

Before executing the update.

Comment: I dont know if it will help, but it might be possible to remove shortcodes <?php remove_all_shortcodes(); ?> prior to running the update

Comment: Maybe you've tried this but you could try `remove_all_filters('the_content')`?

Comment: Thanks all. @ikdekker, that clears the error and I'll add it to my post as a possible solution.